# Var$(X) = \mathbb{E}((X - \mathbb{E}(X))^2) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}(X)^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have a question about something my teacher told us:

let $\mathbb{E}$(X) donate the expected value of a certain random variable $X$.

Then Var$(X) = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}(X))^2] = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb[{E}(X)]^2$. I can't understand why the last equation holds. Can you explain this to me?

Comment: Expand $\mathbb{E}((X - \mathbb{E}(X))^2)$ and use linearity of $\mathbb E$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Expand $\mathbb{E}[(X−\mathbb{E}(X))^2]$ and use linearity of $\mathbb{E}$.

Comment: Exactly what I wrote 7 minutes before

Comment: Thats true, but you said it in a comment, and he therefore could not accept it as the answer to his question XD

Comment: So whenever you want to answer a question, write it as an answer and not in comment, because otherwise someone else can be rewarded for your answer

Comment: With 14K reputation, I do know that. My point is (a) This is more of hint than a full answer, which is why I wrote it as a comment to begin with (b) It is generally considered poor etiquette to rewrite what someone has written elsewhere in the post without expanding on it, such as what Yuval has done below.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry. I just gave it a chance, and I was lucky he accepted the answer. But all credits to you mate

Answer (score 4):

It's a simple calculation. First,
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])^2] =
\mathbb{E}[X^2 + \mathbb{E}[X]^2 - 2X\mathbb{E}[X]].
$$
Linearity of expectation implies
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^2 + \mathbb{E}[X]^2 - 2X\mathbb{E}[X]] =
\mathbb{E}[X^2] + \mathbb{E}[X]^2 - 2\mathbb{E}[X]^2 = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2,
$$
using the fact that $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is a constant.

Comment: Thanks! that helped a lot!